# Ethereum: API call for Total Terminal Difficulty

Tags: json, api, blockchain, ethereum

I see you can get the current block data with

https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_blockNumber&apikey=YourApiKeyToken

and

https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/eth/main

But none have TTL. Any idea how I can get this info? I want to poll it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are arbitrary APIs by services that don't include the raw block data.

If you want to get the raw block data, including its `totalDifficulty`, you need to query an Ethereum node over its JSON-RPC API method [eth_getBlockByNumber](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/#eth_getblockbynumber) or [eth_getBlockByHash](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/#eth_getblockbyhash).

Example with Infura, a well-known 3rd party Ethereum node provider:

```
curl -X POST 'https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/<your_api_key>' \
--data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getBlockByNumber","params":["0x1b4", true],"id":1}'
```

Response contains the `totalDifficulty` param which, according to the docs, represents "integer of the total difficulty of the chain until this block.".

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":{"difficulty":"0x4ea3f27bc","extraData":"0x476574682f4c5649562f76312e302e302f6c696e75782f676f312e342e32","gasLimit":"0x1388","gasUsed":"0x0","hash":"0xdc0818cf78f21a8e70579cb46a43643f78291264dda342ae31049421c82d21ae","logsBloom":"0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","miner":"0xbb7b8287f3f0a933474a79eae42cbca977791171","mixHash":"0x4fffe9ae21f1c9e15207b1f472d5bbdd68c9595d461666602f2be20daf5e7843","nonce":"0x689056015818adbe","number":"0x1b4","parentHash":"0xe99e022112df268087ea7eafaf4790497fd21dbeeb6bd7a1721df161a6657a54","receiptsRoot":"0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421","sha3Uncles":"0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347","size":"0x220","stateRoot":"0xddc8b0234c2e0cad087c8b389aa7ef01f7d79b2570bccb77ce48648aa61c904d","timestamp":"0x55ba467c","totalDifficulty":"0x78ed983323d","transactions":[],"transactionsRoot":"0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421","uncles":[]}
```

Ethereum is scheduled to perform the upgrade to PoS when the total difficulty reaches the threshold of `58,750,000,000,000,000,000,000`.